# Preview to Full-Page Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to expand the `div` on click. An idea is for the `div` to start expanding until its full-page height and width starting from the position of the div before it starts expanding.

I know I didn't explain that to you clearly but I hope my current code will help you understand.

I want to the `div` to expand from its current position to fill the full page. It almost works but it works from the position I set in the animation.

Do you have any idea how can I receive the div's current position in Javascript and set that value as animation's starting point?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.about').click(function() {
    $('.about').addClass('active');
    $('.about').removeClass('border');
  })

  $('.projects').click(function() {
    $('.projects').addClass('active');
    $('.projects').removeClass('border');
  })
})
```

```css
.hero {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 150px);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1.5em;
}

.border {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.about {
  grid-row: 1/2;
  background-color: chocolate;
}

.projects {
  grid-row: 1/3;
  grid-column: 2/3;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#grid-split {
  grid-row: 2/3;
  grid-column: 1/2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1.5em;
}

@keyframes expand {
  0% {
    width: 0vw;
    height: 0vh;
    top: 20%;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.about.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: expand .5s ease-in;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.projects.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  animation: expand .5s ease-in;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="about border"></div>
  <div class="projects border"></div>
  <div id="grid-split">
    <div class="contact border"></div>
    <div class="process border"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```